# Inputting Single Value into SQLiteDatabase

Tags: android, sqlite

I was just wondering if it's possible to just input/update a single value into an SQLiteDatabase (as opposed to an entire row).

The SQLiteDatabase API on the [Android developer site](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html) makes it sound like you can only insert one row at a time (which erases previous information).

An alternative I've been thinking of is to copy the contents of the entire row into an array, alter a value in the array, and then insert the values of the array as an update row in the SQL Database. Does anyone have a more efficient and less roundabout solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The SQLiteDatabase API on the Android developer site makes it sound like you can only insert one row at a time (which erases previous information).

A standard SQL `INSERT` statement does not erase "previous information". It adds a new row to a table.

> I was just wondering if it's possible to just input/update a single value into an SQLiteDatabase (as opposed to an entire row).

By definition, it is not possible to insert a single value into a table. You insert rows into a table. Any columns that you do not provide values for in your `INSERT` statement need to either allow `NULL` values or have default values defined on the table.

A SQL `UPDATE` statement, however, can update a single column in a row. This is true whether you use `update()` or `execSQL()` on `SQLiteDatabase` to update that row.

> then insert the values of the array as an update row in the SQL Database

A standard SQL `INSERT` statement does not update a row. It adds a new row to a table.